# Как правильно организовать ссылки на проекты пользователей в Meteor?

Tags: meteor

Есть пользователи, есть проекты, пользователи работают с несколькими проектами.

Как организовать меню с ссылки подобного плана?
http://localhost:3000/projects/100/settings
где 100 это номер проекта, поменял проект, в меню изменилось id проекта.
Путь выглядит так:

```
Router.route('/projects/:idProject/settings/', {
    name: 'settings'
});
```

сама ссылка в меню тогда выглядит так

```
<a href="{{pathFor 'settings' idProject = idProject}}">
    Настройки
</a>
```

И затык происходит в моем непонимании как правильно получить idProject, где его хранить?
Пробовал в Сессию запихнуть, все круто но при перезагрузке страницы Сессия слетает, сейчас поставил перехватчик: если в сессии нет данных  об проекте то перебрасываем на страницу выбора проекта, выбрал проект, в сессию занесли его номер.
Но этот путь очень грустный на мой взгляд, какие могут быть альтернативы что бы

1. пользователь ввел в браузер без данных в сессии
   http://localhost:3000/projects/01/settings и его перебросило на
   нужную страницу
2. ссылки в меню формировались правильным образом

Навело на мысль что в Router можно через this.params отлавливать id проекта и прописывать его в Сессию если там нет данных, но что-то смущает в этом подходе.

Comment: [Этот пакет](https://github.com/okgrow/meteor-persistent-session) может помочь в сохранении данных сессии после перезагрузки страницы

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете FlowRouter, то idProject очень просто получить так: `FlowRouter.getParam('idProject');`. Для других роутеров существуют аналогичные методы.